# Node async function returns undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, asynchronous

```
var https = require('https');
async function getOrderBook(){
  var options = {
    host: 'api.bybit.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v2/public/orderBook/L2?symbol=BTCUSD',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      //console.log(chunk);
      return chunk;
    });
  }).end();
}

console.log(getOrderBook())
```

The following logs

```
Promise { undefined }
```

in the console. However, I can log it fine from inside the function. How to make it so it waits for the function to resolve?

Comment: Are you missing a `return` statement before `http.request(..)`?

Comment: I get a very long message when I do so but its not the expected response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https.request()` takes a callback function. That's the function you pass in the second argument. When you `return` inside the function you are returning to the caller of *that* function, **not** `getOrderBook()`. Since there are no promises anywhere `async/await` is not really useful. You could wrap the request in a promise and return that, or you can pass a callback to `getOrderBook()` and when the request is finished call it with the data. For example:

```
var https = require('https');

function getOrderBook(cb) {
  var options = {
    host: 'api.bybit.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v2/public/orderBook/L2?symbol=BTCUSD',
    method: 'GET'
  };


  https.request(options, function(res) {
    let data = ''
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      // All done, call the callback
      cb(JSON.parse(data))
    })
  }).end();
}

// pass a callback that tells it what to do with the data
getOrderBook((data) => console.log(data.result))
```

Alternatively you can use a library like axios that has native promise support.

Comment: could you save data.result in a variable?

Comment: You can, but it needs to be saved to a variable after the request is returned. The way javascript works is that it runs all your code *before* the request returns. So you need to deal with the return values in the a callback or a function you call from the callback. This takes a while to get used to with node — but it eventually feels natural..

Comment: how should i approach using data.result for computations then?

Comment: You write a function to do the computations, then call it with the result. `getOrderBook((data) => doComputations(data.result))`. Typically in node, not much happens in the main body of the script — all the action is in functions because you can control when they get called.

Answer (score 0):

You can put `await` before you call the async function, but beware you need to be in an async function to use `await`

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/await

Comment: I still get the long response mentioned in the above comment

Comment: You need to `await getOrderBook` and  `await https.request` and maybe do `return (await http.request())`

Comment: I still get the long unexpected message after I did everything you said, I even wrapped the console.log into an async function with no success